# Bash Script from CMD

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm wanting to automate a bash script to process failure logs from a vendor of ours. We receive daily zip files containing four log files via e-mail. I've worked out how to get Outlook to automatically save the attachment, can unzip the file using Cygwin to get the log files extracted and can move the files around using Cygwin as well but where I'm stuck is how to trigger a the bash script from windows scheduler ... I can get cygwin loaded and running using:

```
set PATH=C:\cygwin\bin;%PATH%

c:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe c:\path\to\bash.script
```

But in the bash script we a looking in specific paths for specific file names and when I enter "2016" in the script, it can't find any files with that name and terminates the script. I'm manually typing in 2016 for the time being and will automate that part later on as well but for the time being I'm stuck trying to get the script to work at all.

The bash script we are using is below. Any suggestions here would be greatly appropriated. Please note I'm not confident at all with unix and am stumbling my way through this. The bash script obviously wasn't written by me either ...

```
#! /bin/bash

while true
do
echo "*****************************************************************"
echo "                  Semble Wallet Server Log Extractor             "
echo "*****************************************************************"
echo "Enter a date [yyyy-mm-dd] :"
read dat
if [[ -z "$dat" ]];
then
    echo "Please enter a valid date......."
    read
    continue
fi

LOG_FOLDER=./log
OP_FOLDER=./log

resFile=$OP_FOLDER/${dat}.csv

echo "Service URL, Cluster Node, Wallet Reference ID, Secure Element ID, IMEI, Wallet Version, Handset OEM, Handset Model, Model Number, OS Version, Request Time, Response Time, Execution Time, Requst Status, Error Code, Error Message" > $resFile

for fName in `find $LOG_FOLDER -name "*${dat}*" -print `
do

    echo Processing : $fName
    fnd=yes

grep -e "^Service URL" \
 -e "^Cluster Node" \
 -e "^Wallet Reference ID" \
 -e "^Secure Element ID" \
 -e "^HandsetID(IMEI)" \
 -e "^Wallet Version" \
 -e "^OEM" \
 -e "^Model Name" \
 -e "^Model Number" \
 -e "^OS Version" \
 -e "^Request Time (NZT/ NZDT)" \
 -e "^Response Time (NZT/ NZDT)" \
 -e "^Request Status" \
 -e "^Error Code" \
 -e "^Error Message" \
 -e "^Service Execution Time"  $fName | sed '/Service Exec/ a\
     \
' | sed -e 's/^.*: //' -e 's/ /;/g'  |

awk -v RS="" ' /FAIL/ { gsub(";", " ", $7);
    gsub(";", " ", $8);
    gsub(";", " ", $9);
    gsub(";", " ", $10);
    gsub(";", " ", $11);
    gsub(";", " ", $12);
    gsub(";", " ", $13);
    gsub(";", " ", $14);
    gsub(";", " ", $15);
    gsub(",", ".", $15);

    printf("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $16, $13, $14,$15 ) }' >> $resFile 

done

if [[ -z "$fnd" ]];
then
     rm $resFile
else
     echo Result File : $resFile
fi

break

done
```

Comment: Sorry I should also note that if I manually open Cygwin (properly) and use the bash script it works absolutely fine.

Comment: *"Any suggestions here would be greatly appropriated."* You're gonna tell your boss you did it yourself? :P

Comment: What if you simply changed `LOG_FOLDER=./log` and `OP_FOLDER=./log` to absolute paths from `C:` to the `log` folder?

Comment: [Shell Check](http://www.shellcheck.net/) it.

Comment: Setting the absolute path didn't work, I'm getting the following errors:

c:\cygwin\home\James\filter3.sh: line 22 C:cygwinhomeJameslog/2016/csv: No such file or directory
find: 'c:cygwinhomeJameslog': No such file or directory
rm: cannot rempove 'c:cygwinhomeJameslog/2016.csv': No such file or directory

Comment: @JamesStewart `C:cygwinhomeJameslog/2016/csv: No such file or directory`. Do you notice that the backslashes are missing here? Backslashes have special meaning (as escape characters) in shell/bash and many other languages. You have a few options but since the rest of your script also adds forward slashes and you can't mix forward/backslashes, try using forward slashes in your path like so: `C:/cygwin/home/James/log/...`

Comment: Are you sure you actually have the `find` binary in your path? In Unix, the find command is not internal to bash, but actually an external executable - not sure about how it is structured in Cygwin, but presumably the same. In that case you may need to provide the full path to find.exe (assuming there is a Cygwin equivalent)